# Spring Quartz Execute Time

Tags: spring, quartz

I have set an spring quertz timer with following expressions:

`@Scheduled(cron = "${quartz.expire.data.cron:0 0 0 * * ?}")`

But it starts a little bit ahead as shown in our logs:

`2017-10-22 23:59:59.899 scheduler-4`

Why?

Comment: Could you please share the complete log trace, so will be easy to find issue and also post your code snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

This might come from the calculation for the next execution time.

In the [`schedule`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ReschedulingRunnable.java#66) method of the `ReschedulingRunnable`, the time is taken from the `nextExecutionTime` at line 68. The actual delay until execution gets calculated at line 72.

```
66  public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule() {
67      synchronized (this.triggerContextMonitor) {
68          this.scheduledExecutionTime = this.trigger.nextExecutionTime(this.triggerContext);
69          if (this.scheduledExecutionTime == null) {
70              return null;
71          }
72          long initialDelay = this.scheduledExecutionTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
73          this.currentFuture = this.executor.schedule(this, initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
74          return this;
75      }
76  }
```

Now let's see what happens in the `nextExecutionTime` method of the  [`CronTrigger`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.java#73):

```
72  @Override
73  public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
74      Date date = triggerContext.lastCompletionTime();
75      if (date != null) {
76          Date scheduled = triggerContext.lastScheduledExecutionTime();
77          if (scheduled != null && date.before(scheduled)) {
78              // Previous task apparently executed too early...
79              // Let's simply use the last calculated execution time then,
80              // in order to prevent accidental re-fires in the same second.
81              date = scheduled;
82          }
83      }
84      else {
85          date = new Date();
86      }
87      return this.sequenceGenerator.next(date);
88  }
```

At Line 86, the time is taken. The taken moment is the base to calculate the next execution time for the cron definition which happens in [`sequenceGenerator.next`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.java#114)

```
134     Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
135     calendar.setTimeZone(this.timeZone);
136     calendar.setTime(date);
137
138     // First, just reset the milliseconds and try to calculate from there...
139     calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
140     long originalTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
141     doNext(calendar, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
142
143     if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() == originalTimestamp) {
144         // We arrived at the original timestamp - round up to the next whole second and try again...
145         calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
146         doNext(calendar, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
147     }
148
149     return calendar.getTime();
```

This certainly takes a few milliseconds, which will be missing within the  `initialDelay`.

**Proof**

A small test to proof this looks like following. I create a regular `CronTrigger`, and a manipulated `CronTrigger`

```
@Test
public void test() {
    CronTrigger normalTrigger= new CronTrigger("0 0 0 * * ?");
    Date d2 = normalTrigger.nextExecutionTime(new SimpleTriggerContext());
    long initialDelay2 = d2.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Normal trigger:"+ initialDelay2);

    //create a manipulated trigger, which takes longer to return the nextExecutionTime
    CronTrigger manipulated = new CronTrigger("0 0 0 * * ?") {
        @Override
        public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
            Date nextExecutionTime = super.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              //ignore
            }
            return nextExecutionTime;
        }
    };
    Date d = manipulated.nextExecutionTime(new SimpleTriggerContext());
    long initialDelay = d.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Manipulated trigger:" +initialDelay);
}
```

From the result, you see that the manipulated trigger will trigger 5 seconds earlier than the non-manipulated, because it took 5 seconds longer to return the `nextExecutionTime`.